# Error al cambiar password utilizando templateview y método def post

Tags: python, django

Tratando de hacer la funcionalidad de set_password, me devuelve el siguiente error:

Error:
![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

Views.py

```
  class UserChangePasswordView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/change_password.html'
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login')

    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            old_password = request.POST.get('old_password')
            new_password = request.POST.get('new_password')
            repeat_new_password = request.POST.get('repeat_new_password')

            if new_password == repeat_new_password:
                current_user = request.user
                current_user_id = current_user.id

                u = User.objects.get(id=current_user_id)
                u.set_password(new_password)
                u.save()
```

forms.py

```
    class PasswordChangeForm(forms.Form):
    
        old_password = forms.CharField(
            label='Password actual',
            required=True,
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={
                    'placeholder': '',
                    'class': 'form-control form-control-lg'
                }
            )
        )
        new_password = forms.CharField(
            label='Nuevo password',
            required=True,
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={
                    'placeholder': '',
                    'class': 'form-control form-control-lg'
                }
            )
        )
    
        repeat_new_password = forms.CharField(
            label='Repira el nuevo password',
            required=True,
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={
                    'placeholder': '',
                    'class': 'form-control form-control-lg'
                }
            )
        )
```

urls.py

```
     path(
            'change_password',
            views.UserChangePasswordView.as_view(),
            name='change_password',
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

La siguiente solución consigue aplicar `set_password()`.

View:

```py
class UserChangePasswordView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/change_password.html'
    form_class = PasswordChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users_app:user-login')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        old_password = request.POST.get('old_password')
        new_password = request.POST.get('new_password')
        repeat_new_password = request.POST.get('repeat_new_password')

        if new_password == repeat_new_password:
            current_user = request.user
            current_user_id = current_user.id

            u = User.objects.get(id=current_user_id)
            u.set_password(new_password)
            u.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('users_app:user-login')
        else:  
            return HttpResponseRedirect('users_app:change_password')
```